# Can't retrieve value from text inputs with the serialize() only hidden values with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

For some reason I can't retrieve value from text inputs with the serialize() form inputs function in jquery.

If i the inputs are type="text" console.log returns:

```
position_id=229&step=1&name=&email=
```

If the inputs are type="hidden" and a value="test" is added console.log returns:

```
position_id=229&step=1&name=test&email=test@test.com
```

This is my form:

```
<form id="referral-form" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="position_id" value="{{$position->id}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />
    <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="name" required/>
    <input name="email" class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="email" required />
    <div class="button submit"></div>
</form>
```

and here is my javascript event:

```
onRefer: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $("#referral-form");

    console.log($form.serialize());

}
```

Comment: [Your code works just fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/bghLoorc/) Of course, you have to type something into the input fields.

Comment: @Pointy ty. So there is something else fishy going on...

Comment: What is the `onRefer` event in your code?